# Obtain all the intervals from a list of numbers that sometime repeat

Tags: list, file, math, numbers, missing-data

I would like to find a method to obtain all the intervals from a list of files. The files represent pages of scanned documents. Sometimes the documents had several pages and the number of the documents appears several times, but most of the times the documents had just one page. What I would like to find out is which documents were scanned and which not, which numbers are missing from the list.

The list of files looks like this:

```
00001_DCT.jpeg
00002_DCT.jpeg
00003_1d2_DCT.jpeg
00003_2d2_DCT.jpeg
00004_1d3_DCT.jpeg
00004_2d3_DCT.jpeg
00004_3d3_DCT.jpeg
00005_1d9_DCT.jpeg
00005_2d9_DCT.jpeg
00005_3d9_DCT.jpeg
00005_4d9_DCT.jpeg
00005_5d9_DCT.jpeg
00005_6d9_DCT.jpeg
00005_7d9_DCT.jpeg
00005_8d9_DCT.jpeg
00005_9d9_DCT.jpeg
00006_1d4_DCT.jpeg
00006_2d4_DCT.jpeg
00006_3d4_DCT.jpeg
00006_4d4_DCT.jpeg
00007_DCT.jpeg
00008_DCT.jpeg
00009.jpeg
00010.jpeg
```

up to

```
24679.jpeg
24680_1d3.jpeg
24680_2d3.jpeg
24680_3d3.jpeg
24681_1d2.jpeg
24681_2d2_dct.jpeg
24682.jpeg
24683_1d2.jpeg
24683_2d2.jpeg
```

Which is the easier way to find the missing numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that if a document was scanned, it was scanned completely (ie not going from 1d3 to 3d3).

Loop through your file names, converting the first 5 characters into a number. Make sure the current file number is only greater than the previous file number by 1 or 0. If that case isn't met, there is a break (all files between the current file number and previous one are missing).